# Where do I place the main method and while loops for this purchase.java and createpurchase.java?

Tags: java

I am working on intro to java programming homework. The question is:

Create a class named Purchase. Each Purchase contains an invoice number, amount of sale, and amount of sales tax. Include set methods for the invoice number and sale amount. Within the set() method for the sale amount, calculate the sales tax as 5% of the sale amount. Also include a display method that displays a purchase’s details. Save as Purchase.class b. Create an application that declares a Purchase object and prompts the user for purchase details. When you prompt for an invoice number, do not let the user proceed until a number between 1,000 and 8,000 has been entered. When you prompt for a sale amount, do not proceed until the user has entered a nonnegative value. After a valid Purchase object has been created, display the object’s invoice number, sale amount, and sales tax.

Here is the code I have for a.

```
public class Purchase
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
int invoiceNumber = 50;
double salePrice = 10.00;
double SalesTax;
}

public void setInvoiceNumber(int invoice)
{
    invoiceNumber = invoice;
}

public void setSalePrice(double saleAmount)
{
    salePrice = saleAmount;
    SalesTax = (saleAmount * .05);
}

public void displaySalePrice()
{
    System.out.println("Your invoice number is:" + invoiceNumber);
    System.out.println("Your sale amount is: " + salePrice);
    System.out.println("Your sales tax is: " + SalesTax);
}

}
```

Errors:

> DDescription  Resource    Path    Location    Type invoiceNumber cannot be
>   resolved to a variable    Purchase.java   /Purchase/src   line 13 Java
>   Problem invoiceNumber cannot be resolved to a
>   variable  Purchase.java   /Purchase/src   line 24 Java Problem salePrice
>   cannot be resolved to a variable  Purchase.java   /Purchase/src   line
>   18    Java Problem salePrice cannot be resolved to a
>   variable  Purchase.java   /Purchase/src   line 25 Java Problem SalesTax
>   cannot be resolved to a variable  Purchase.java   /Purchase/src   line
>   19    Java Problem SalesTax cannot be resolved to a
>   variable  Purchase.java   /Purchase/src   line 26 Java Problem

...  When I run it without a main method it says there are no errors but that it cannot run without a main method (of course).  How do I resolve these to variables?

Comment: At least you're honest about the homework part.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html

Comment: Also, please read up on use if fields. Continue studying your basic Java texts as these will help you much more than this site can or will.

Answer (score -1):

When I set my projects up, I usually just create a Main class that I put my `main` method in. Since you're declaring objects, you should have no problem with it here. Just make sure you import the files for your objects like this...

```
import Purchase;
```

(provided that the files are in the same folder)

Comment: This did nothing to my code.

Answer (score -2):

> It says the main method is not found, which I understand it is not there but I don't know where to put it.

Put it in the class that you've posted.

> I have tried a few different spots but I always get the error that the variables are not compatible with a static declaration.

So you've got a but in your code attempt.

> Where do I put the main method?

How the heck should we know if you don't post your attempt?

Show your actual attempt and any and all error messages, and we'll be able to give you decent help.

Comment: When I try to insert a main method it creates errors that it "cannot make a static reference to the non-static field" of all my variables and it makes it so that each variable "cannot be resolved to a variable".  Do you know why?

Comment: @Tyler.Borer: edit your original question, show your attempt, and show all error messages.

Comment: @Tyler.Borer: and have you searched on "cannot make static reference to a non-static field"? that is a very common newbie Java error, and the sooner you learn about how to use object oriented techniques with Java, the better. The same for your other error -- search on the error message and **learn** what it means!

Comment: I just looked it up.  If your referring to adding static in their declaration, I have tried that earlier, as well as in their set methods.

Comment: @Tyler.Borer: keep looking things up, as you're still off the mark. I see that you've updated your question's code, but note that in your current main method, you don't try to create a Purchase object -- why not? The class is a Purchase class and it so far seems to be geared towards creating Purchase objects, something that you're not doing. Your question suggests that you might benefit from studying your texts/tutorials a bit more. Please don't neglect learning the basics as they will help you progress.